# How to use TLS_PSK in java on both server side and client side

Tags: java, ssl, dtls, java-security

i want to use TLS-PSK on both server side and client side in java. I have found a few tutorials which gives instructions to use it on client side. But i dont have any clue for using it on server side.

Do i need to do any configuration changes  in jetty/apache server for it

[Java 8 enhancement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-8.html) says, TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 on the client by default.

Plz give me any guidence about it.

or can anyone give any way to confirm , if there is no support for it in java on server side.

Answer (score 4):

JSSE imeplements TLS protocol for Java, uses JCA internally.
TLS is much more than just PSK, it uses Cipher suites for authorization, cofidentiality etc...

if you want just PSK, then in order to build a key from shared secret, the key derivation function should be used. Use symmetric key algorithm for that.
https://www.flexiprovider.de/examples/ExampleCrypt.html

Then, send encoded data, however you want.

Comment: i know how to encrypt a file and decrypt it. But i want to use it between a servlet and a client.

Comment: so you have to enable https on your container; 1. you need to generate key pair and put it into keystore, then in tomcat configuration you have to point to your keystore. That's it. now your client access your server on https port you defined in tomcat configuration. as a part of TLS protocol, they will settle which symetric and asymetric encryption will be used. You  can't provide your own symetric key.

Comment: You can only specify cipher suite tomcat connetor which will be used by server to negotiate algorithms with client : http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#BIO_specific_configuration

Comment: i have been asked to work on both approaches using certificate and symmetric key. I have used keytool to generate jks files. I have mentioned path to jks files in server.xml of tomcat and loadKeyMaterial function of SSLContextBuilder. It is working now.

Is it symmetric key approach or certificate approach, because i have done this using steps i got while searching client certificate authentication.

I have exported public key from keystore to a .cer file and imported it to trust_store.jks file to use as trust_store